# Trac sqlite date query

Tags: sqlite, datetime, timestamp, trac

I am having a hell of a time generating a report with dates of creation for my tickets.

here is my sqlite query( I am directly querying the db)

```
.header on
.mode csv
.output opentickets.csv
SELECT DISTINCT
   id AS ticket, summary, status, priority, t.type AS type, 
   owner, time as created

  FROM ticket t, ticket_custom q
  LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
  WHERE t.id = q.ticket AND status <> 'closed'
 ORDER BY  priority, time;
```

But the value I get for the time of creation is garbage:
I get 1341324096360000
when I should get
2012-07-03

I have tried unix epoch time conversion...
query:

```
.header on
.mode csv
.output opentickets.csv
SELECT DISTINCT
   id AS ticket, summary, status, priority, t.type AS type, 
   owner, datetime(time, 'unixepoch') as created

  FROM ticket t, ticket_custom q
  LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
  WHERE t.id = q.ticket AND status <> 'closed'
 ORDER BY  priority, time;
```

I get:  -1413-03-01 13:07:12

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

CL is correct that the time is stored in microseconds.  You can see here in the [schema](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema/TicketSystem) that the field for time is an int64 and in the [release notes](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/ReleaseNotes/0.12) for .12 the say that they have changed the time from "seconds since epoch" to "microseconds since epoch".

As for my experience with displaying time in Trac queries, I did not have to do any conversion.  Here is a query that I use to display all changed tickets for the last 7 days.  As you can see, I show the ticket change time as part of the select and Trac formats it correctly.  Trac will auto format created, modified, date, time field  as a date and/or time.  See this [Trac wiki page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports#Automaticallyformattedcolumns) for more details.

```
    SELECT 
tc.Ticket AS ticket, 
tc.Time as time, 
c.value as  __group__,
ifnull(tc.Newvalue,0) as total,
tc.Author  AS author,         
tc.Field as field     
from ticket_change tc 
LEFT JOIN ticket t on t.id = tc.ticket
LEFT JOIN ticket_custom c on c.ticket = tc.ticket and c.name= 'customer'
LEFT JOIN ticket_custom tt on tt.ticket = tc.ticket and tt.name = 'totalhours'
where field = 'hours' and c.Value is not null
and tc.Time > strftime('%s',CURRENT_DATE-7) +0
and tc.Time < strftime('%s',CURRENT_DATE) +0
and tc.Author = $USER
and tt.value is not null
```

If you are looking to do some special fomatting, look at the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) on time but here is a quick example

```
strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time / 1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Unix timestamps are in seconds, but it appears these values are microseconds:

```
> SELECT datetime(1341324096360000 / 1000000, 'unixepoch');
2012-07-03 14:01:36
```